# How to determine when ListView fling is slowing down

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, baseadapter

In order to improve performance for list scrolling I have [implemented this suggestion](http://www.programmingmobile.com/2012/03/buttery-smooth-list-scrolling-in.html) And it definitely improves performance.

Mine is implemented as such

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    switch (scrollState) {
        case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
            adapter.busy = false;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL:
            adapter.busy = true;
            break;
        case OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING:
            adapter.busy = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

However, I would like to make it visually a little more appealing, by setting adapter.busy to be false as soon as the list scroll speed crosses a certain threshold. However, I have figured out no good way to determine the scroll speed, while it is scrolling. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately not really, we changed a lot of since then to where scrolling performance is not as much of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can get the scroll position at any time.  Use a CountdownTimer to check the latest scroll position periodically, and compare with the previous scroll position(s) to determine direction and velocity.  If its moving too fast update according. Once you have implemented please post result as above.  (There might also be a scroll position change event or you might utilize perhaps on focus event changes to determine this).

Answer (score 0):

Had similar request, and the following works for me.
Only need to try out what is the best for MIN_VELOCITY

```
@Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                int totalItemCount) {

            checkFlingVelocitySlowDown(firstVisibleItem, totalItemCount);
        }

int mLastScrollInTopItemPosition = 0;
long mLastTimeTopPositionChanged = System.currentTimeMillis();
final double MIN_VELOCITY = 0.01;
final int TOP_VIEW_ITEMS_RANGE = 3;
final int BOTTOM_VIEW_RANGE = 6;

void checkFlingVelocitySlowDown(int scrollInTopItemPosition, int totalItemCount) {
    try {
        if (mLastScrollInTopItemPosition != scrollInTopItemPosition) {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeSpan = now - mLastTimeTopPositionChanged;
            double velocity = (timeSpan > 0) ? (1.0 / timeSpan) : 1000000;
            mLastScrollInTopItemPosition = scrollInTopItemPosition;
            mLastTimeTopPositionChanged = now;

            if (velocity <= MIN_VELOCITY ||
                    scrollInTopItemPosition <= TOP_VIEW_ITEMS_RANGE ||
                    (Math.abs(totalItemCount - scrollInTopItemPosition) < BOTTOM_VIEW_RANGE)) {
                // to what ever it should do when scroll closer to top or bottom, or fling is slowing down
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```